# Sending Survey to a list

Tags: apex, process-builder, process, salesforce-survey

I have been asked to add a button to contact list ,
where the button will send survey invitation to all marked contacts.
Salesforce have this wonderful tool on surveys:
[image]

Is there any way to send this formatted email via apex code?

Current solution:
Visualforce page get the contacts form list view, apex controller updates a field on contact which triggers a process that send the email.
Problem here, process can't parametrized the survey name.
(We should create different process per survey)

Any suggestions here?

Comment: You can create survey invitation and survey subject from apex and create a email alert which triggers on survey invitation getting created

Comment: Yes, But survey invitation and survey subject does not hold participant name and questions.  Plus formatting is not ready. What is Survey subject is for?

Comment: surveyinvitation will contain survey name which will then connect to question and all,and survey subject will relate surveyinviation and case(or whatever other object you want survey on)

Comment: you have to put email on a custom field of invitation so that you can use it in workflow email alerts

Comment: Hi @User6670, So my other solution will be creating survey invitation object from apex code, populating custom email field on invitation. How Do I get the question\recpient name on template? Is it possible to style it from email template? I would be happy If you can share here maybe an exmaple email template HTML.

Comment: it would only work if you want the whole survey link to be sent in Email, not separate question,if you want i can write the solution

Comment: i didn't saw you want to send separate question

Comment: I created the solution, I miss two things: 1. Styled email template. 2. Reaching the participant field on template.  Would be greatfull if you can publish something like this.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this satisfy your needs but here is something yo can try,
you can query community and survey and whatever parent you want survey to relate considering you are getting contacts id

```
 Id communityId = [select Id from Network where Name = 'CommunityName'].Id;
  Survey Surveyrec = [Select Id from Survey where Name = 'SurveyName'];

   SurveyInvitation SInv = New SurveyInvitation();


   Sinv.CommunityId = communityId;

   SInv.Name = "whatevername";
   SInv.name__c=contact.name;//you can have several custom fields like this one which store name of contact
   SInv.Survey__c=Surveyrec.name;//custom field for survey name

   SInv.OptionsCollectAnonymousResponse = false;
   SInv.OptionsAllowGuestUserResponse = true;
   SInv.SurveyId = Surveyrec.Id;

   insert SInv;

   SurveySubject SS = new SurveySubject();

   SS.SubjectId = contactid;
   SS.ParentId = SInv.Id;//
   SS.Name = CaseNumber;

   insert SS;
```

then you can create workflow which triggers when survey invitation are created and trigger email alert then you can create an email template  and put survey inviation merge fields
for invitation link

```
https://yourcommunityurl/survey/runtimeApp.app?invitationId={!SurveyInvitation.Id}&surveyName={SurveyInvitation.surveyname__c}&UUID={!SurveyInvitation.UUID}
```

you can create some custom field to store name and community url too and use it as merge fields in email template

Comment: Thank you! The reason you cannot use the same email format is that custom solution is based on classic email templates while salesforce's native is based on lightning email templates.

Comment: Hi @User6670,Thx again for the detailed answer.      
Though, I cannot wonder if there is no api for sending email invitation the same as in the survey page.

Comment: @shakedmezuman as of now i dont think there is any other way of sending survey from apex